# MongoDB Object Serialized as JSON

Tags: django, mongodb, pymongo, simplejson

I'm attempting to send a JSON encoded MongoDB object back in my HTTP response. I've followed several other similar questions but am still missing something. No exceptions are thrown, but I get a cryptic `<api.views.MongoEncoder object at 0x80a0c02c>` response in the browser. I'm sure it's something simple, but any help would be appreciated.

Function:

```
from django.utils.simplejson import JSONEncoder
from pymongo.objectid import ObjectId

class MongoEncoder( JSONEncoder ):
     def _iterencode( self, o, markers = None ):
          if isinstance( o, ObjectId ):
               return """ObjectId("%s")""" % str(o)
          else:
               return JSONEncoder._iterencode(self, o, markers)
```

views.py:

```
user = User({
    's_email': request.GET.get('s_email', ''),
    's_password': request.GET.get('s_password', ''),
    's_first_name': request.GET.get('s_first_name', ''),
    's_last_name': request.GET.get('s_last_name', ''),
    'd_birthdate': request.GET.get('d_birthdate', ''),
    's_gender': request.GET.get('s_gender', ''),
    's_city': request.GET.get('s_city', ''),
    's_state': request.GET.get('s_state', ''),
})

response = {
    's_status': 'success',
    'data': user
}
return HttpResponse(MongoEncoder( response ))
```

I'm on Python 2.4, pymongo, simplejson.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

In newer versions of `simplejson` (and the `json` module in Python 2.7) you implement the `default` method in your subclasses:

```
from json import JSONEncoder
from pymongo.objectid import ObjectId

class MongoEncoder(JSONEncoder):
    def default(self, obj, **kwargs):
        if isinstance(obj, ObjectId):
            return str(obj)
        else:            
            return JSONEncoder.default(obj, **kwargs)
```

You could then use the encoder with `MongoEncoder().encode(obj)` or `json.dumps(obj, cls=MongoEncoder)`.

Comment: If you can't find pymongo.objectid, try bson.objectid.

Comment: Based on this answer, http://stackoverflow.com/a/10401553, ObjectID is no longer in pymongo.object id. Instead, use: import bson.objectid

Comment: Also, you can use the bson dumps that handle ObjectId `from bson.json_util import dumps` see http://stackoverflow.com/a/18405626/1346682