# MongoKit "ImportError: No module named objectid " error

Tags: python, python-2.7, flask, pymongo, mongokit

I get some very strange error using MongoKit:

```
>>> from mongokit import *
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/mongokit/__init__.py", line 35, in <module>
    from document import Document, ObjectId
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/mongokit/document.py", line 48, in <module>
    from pymongo.objectid import ObjectId
ImportError: No module named objectid
```

I tried everything to find the reason but nothing helps.
Actually I googled "ImportError: No module named objectid" error and it has no results at all. I tried to use MongoKit following the simple tutorial http://namlook.github.com/mongokit/introduction.html#a-quick-example and the first line of the tutorial produces this strange error. Below is the log of MongoKit installation.

What I'm doing wrong?

```
user@server:~$ sudo pip install mongokit
Downloading/unpacking mongokit
  Downloading mongokit-0.7.2.tar.gz (69Kb): 69Kb downloaded
  Running setup.py egg_info for package mongokit

Downloading/unpacking pymongo>=2.0.1 (from mongokit)
  Downloading pymongo-2.2.tar.gz (228Kb): 228Kb downloaded
  Running setup.py egg_info for package pymongo

Downloading/unpacking anyjson>=0.2.2 (from mongokit)
  Downloading anyjson-0.3.1.tar.gz
  Running setup.py egg_info for package anyjson

Installing collected packages: mongokit, pymongo, anyjson
  Running setup.py install for mongokit

  Running setup.py install for pymongo
    building 'bson._cbson' extension
    gcc -pthread -fno-strict-aliasing -DNDEBUG -g -fwrapv -O2 -Wall -Wstrict-prototypes -fPIC -Ibson -I/usr/include/python2.7 -c bson/_cbsonmodule.c -o build/temp.linux-i686-2.7/bson/_cbsonmodule.o
    gcc -pthread -fno-strict-aliasing -DNDEBUG -g -fwrapv -O2 -Wall -Wstrict-prototypes -fPIC -Ibson -I/usr/include/python2.7 -c bson/time64.c -o build/temp.linux-i686-2.7/bson/time64.o
    gcc -pthread -fno-strict-aliasing -DNDEBUG -g -fwrapv -O2 -Wall -Wstrict-prototypes -fPIC -Ibson -I/usr/include/python2.7 -c bson/buffer.c -o build/temp.linux-i686-2.7/bson/buffer.o
    gcc -pthread -fno-strict-aliasing -DNDEBUG -g -fwrapv -O2 -Wall -Wstrict-prototypes -fPIC -Ibson -I/usr/include/python2.7 -c bson/encoding_helpers.c -o build/temp.linux-i686-2.7/bson/encoding_helpers.o
    gcc -pthread -shared -Wl,-O1 -Wl,-Bsymbolic-functions -Wl,-Bsymbolic-functions -Wl,-z,relro build/temp.linux-i686-2.7/bson/_cbsonmodule.o build/temp.linux-i686-2.7/bson/time64.o build/temp.linux-i686-2.7/bson/buffer.o build/temp.linux-i686-2.7/bson/encoding_helpers.o -o build/lib.linux-i686-2.7/bson/_cbson.so
    building 'pymongo._cmessage' extension
    gcc -pthread -fno-strict-aliasing -DNDEBUG -g -fwrapv -O2 -Wall -Wstrict-prototypes -fPIC -Ibson -I/usr/include/python2.7 -c pymongo/_cmessagemodule.c -o build/temp.linux-i686-2.7/pymongo/_cmessagemodule.o
    gcc -pthread -fno-strict-aliasing -DNDEBUG -g -fwrapv -O2 -Wall -Wstrict-prototypes -fPIC -Ibson -I/usr/include/python2.7 -c bson/buffer.c -o build/temp.linux-i686-2.7/bson/buffer.o
    gcc -pthread -shared -Wl,-O1 -Wl,-Bsymbolic-functions -Wl,-Bsymbolic-functions -Wl,-z,relro build/temp.linux-i686-2.7/pymongo/_cmessagemodule.o build/temp.linux-i686-2.7/bson/buffer.o -o build/lib.linux-i686-2.7/pymongo/_cmessage.so

  Running setup.py install for anyjson

Successfully installed mongokit pymongo anyjson
Cleaning up...
```

Answer (score 11, accepted):

It's an error in the dependencies. As of [PyMongo 1.11](http://api.mongodb.org/python/1.11/api/index.html) [`objectid` lives in the `bson` module, not `pymongo`](http://api.mongodb.org/python/current/api/index.html).

Comment: Is there any way to solve it? Or should I re-write 3rd party source code? It's a very basic thing, actually the first line of the tutorial and doesn't work. 'coz all I'm doing - just importing "from mongokit import *"

Comment: Keep in mind it's not yet pulled in. Alternatively, you could try downgrading to 2.1.1, that should be the last version with the fallback.

Answer (score 10):

As Electro said, it's a Bug.

I used the following dirty little hack to keep my site running until it is fixed:

```
import sys
import pymongo
import bson.objectid
pymongo.objectid = bson.objectid
sys.modules["pymongo.objectid"] = bson.objectid
```