# TypeError: ObjectId('') is not JSON serializable

Tags: python, json, mongodb, flask

My response back from MongoDB after querying an aggregated function on document using Python, It returns valid response and i can print it but can not return it.

Error:

```
TypeError: ObjectId('51948e86c25f4b1d1c0d303c') is not JSON serializable
```

Print:

```
{'result': [{'_id': ObjectId('51948e86c25f4b1d1c0d303c'), 'api_calls_with_key': 4, 'api_calls_per_day': 0.375, 'api_calls_total': 6, 'api_calls_without_key': 2}], 'ok': 1.0}
```

But When i try to return:

```
TypeError: ObjectId('51948e86c25f4b1d1c0d303c') is not JSON serializable
```

It is RESTfull call:

```
@appv1.route('/v1/analytics')
def get_api_analytics():
    # get handle to collections in MongoDB
    statistics = sldb.statistics

    objectid = ObjectId("51948e86c25f4b1d1c0d303c")

    analytics = statistics.aggregate([
    {'$match': {'owner': objectid}},
    {'$project': {'owner': "$owner",
    'api_calls_with_key': {'$cond': [{'$eq': ["$apikey", None]}, 0, 1]},
    'api_calls_without_key': {'$cond': [{'$ne': ["$apikey", None]}, 0, 1]}
    }},
    {'$group': {'_id': "$owner",
    'api_calls_with_key': {'$sum': "$api_calls_with_key"},
    'api_calls_without_key': {'$sum': "$api_calls_without_key"}
    }},
    {'$project': {'api_calls_with_key': "$api_calls_with_key",
    'api_calls_without_key': "$api_calls_without_key",
    'api_calls_total': {'$add': ["$api_calls_with_key", "$api_calls_without_key"]},
    'api_calls_per_day': {'$divide': [{'$add': ["$api_calls_with_key", "$api_calls_without_key"]}, {'$dayOfMonth': datetime.now()}]},
    }}
    ])


    print(analytics)

    return analytics
```

db is well connected and collection is there too and I got back valid expected result but when i try to return it gives me Json error. Any idea how to convert the response back into JSON. Thanks

Answer (score 168, accepted):

You should define you own [`JSONEncoder`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/json.html#json.JSONEncoder) and using it:

```
import json
from bson import ObjectId

class JSONEncoder(json.JSONEncoder):
    def default(self, o):
        if isinstance(o, ObjectId):
            return str(o)
        return json.JSONEncoder.default(self, o)

JSONEncoder().encode(analytics)
```

It's also possible to use it in the following way.

```
json.encode(analytics, cls=JSONEncoder)
```

Comment: Perfect! It worked for me. I already have a Json encoder class, How can i merge that with yours class?My already Json encode class is: 
'class MyJsonEncoder(json.JSONEncoder):
    def default(self, obj):
        if isinstance(obj, datetime):
            return str(obj.strftime("%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S"))
        return json.JSONEncoder.default(self, obj)'

Comment: @IrfanDayan, just add `if isinstance(o, ObjectId): return str(o)` before `return` in method `default`.

Comment: Could you add `from bson import ObjectId`, so everybody can copy-paste even faster? Thanks!

Comment: @defuz Why not just use `str`? What's wrong with that approach?

Comment: @defuz: When I try to use this, ObjectID is removed, but my json response is broken into single characters. I mean when I print each element from the resulting json in a for loop I get each character as an element. Any idea how to solve this?

Comment: `return json.JSONEncoder.default(self, o)` better written as `return supper().default(self, o)`

Answer (score 234):

[Bson](https://api.mongodb.com/python/3.4.0/api/bson/index.html) in PyMongo distribution provides [json_util](https://api.mongodb.com/python/3.4.0/api/bson/json_util.html) - you can use that one instead to handle BSON types

```
from bson import json_util

def parse_json(data):
    return json.loads(json_util.dumps(data))
```

Comment: I agree with @tim, this is correct way to deal with BSON data coming from mongo.

http://api.mongodb.org/python/current/api/bson/json_util.html

Comment: Yes, seems to be more of a hassle free if we use this way

Comment: That's the best way actually.

Comment: An example here would be a little more helpful, as this is the best way but the linked documentation isn't the most user friendly for noobs

Comment: `from bson import json_util`

`json.loads(json_util.dumps(user_collection))`


^ this worked after installing python-bsonjs with `pipenv install python-bsonjs`

Comment: json_util comes from bson NOT from pymongo from my view

Comment: Please fix broken link http://api.mongodb.org/python/current/index.html

Comment: Update the link: https://pymongo.readthedocs.io/en/stable/api/bson/json_util.html

Answer (score 59):

Most users who receive the "not JSON serializable" error simply need to specify **`default=str`** when using [`json.dumps`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/json.html#json.dump). For example:

```
json.dumps(my_obj, default=str)
```

This will force a conversion to `str`, preventing the error. Of course then look at the generated output to confirm that it is what you need.

Comment: This should be accepted answer! It cleanly solves the ObjectId issue. As @Asclepius says make sure it doesn't impact other json entries

Comment: I agree - it's both the simplest answer and has no (obvious) side effects.

Comment: Easy and clean implentation without the need to use `bson`, if theres a desire to omit oid, and create a 'flat' dictionary (with just the _id key and remaining attributes) . Even though this returns the exscaped quotes, passing the returned escaped JSON to json.loads converts it back to a Python dictionary

Answer (score 53):

```
>>> from bson import Binary, Code
>>> from bson.json_util import dumps
>>> dumps([{'foo': [1, 2]},
...        {'bar': {'hello': 'world'}},
...        {'code': Code("function x() { return 1; }")},
...        {'bin': Binary("")}])
'[{"foo": [1, 2]}, {"bar": {"hello": "world"}}, {"code": {"$code": "function x() { return 1; }", "$scope": {}}}, {"bin": {"$binary": "AQIDBA==", "$type": "00"}}]'
```

Actual example from [json_util](http://api.mongodb.org/python/current/api/bson/json_util.html).

Unlike Flask's jsonify, "dumps" will return a string, so it cannot be used as a 1:1 replacement of Flask's jsonify.

But [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19877903/using-mongo-with-flask-and-python) shows that we can serialize using json_util.dumps(), convert back to dict using json.loads() and finally call Flask's jsonify on it.

Example (derived from previous question's answer):

```
from bson import json_util, ObjectId
import json

#Lets create some dummy document to prove it will work
page = {'foo': ObjectId(), 'bar': [ObjectId(), ObjectId()]}

#Dump loaded BSON to valid JSON string and reload it as dict
page_sanitized = json.loads(json_util.dumps(page))
return page_sanitized
```

This solution will convert ObjectId and others (ie Binary, Code, etc) to a string equivalent such as "$oid."

JSON output would look like this:

```
{
  "_id": {
    "$oid": "abc123"
  }
}
```

Comment: Just to clarify, no need to call 'jsonify' directly from a Flask request handler - just return the sanitized result.

Comment: You're absolutely right. A Python dict (which json.loads returns) should automatically be jsonified by Flask.

Comment: Isn't a dict object not callable?

Comment: @rick112358 how does a dict not being callable relate to this Q&A?

Comment: you can also use json_util.loads() to get the exact same dictionary back (instead of one with '$oid' key).

Answer (score 25):

```
from bson import json_util
import json

@app.route('/')
def index():
    for _ in "collection_name".find():
        return json.dumps(i, indent=4, default=json_util.default)
```

**This is the sample example for converting BSON into JSON object. You can try this.**

Answer (score 17):

As a quick replacement, you can change `{'owner': objectid}` to `{'owner': str(objectid)}`.

But defining your own `JSONEncoder` is a better solution, it depends on your requirements.

Answer (score 15):

Posting here as I think it may be useful for people using `Flask` with `pymongo`. This is my current "best practice" setup for allowing flask to marshall pymongo bson data types.

*mongoflask.py*

```
from datetime import datetime, date

import isodate as iso
from bson import ObjectId
from flask.json import JSONEncoder
from werkzeug.routing import BaseConverter


class MongoJSONEncoder(JSONEncoder):
    def default(self, o):
        if isinstance(o, (datetime, date)):
            return iso.datetime_isoformat(o)
        if isinstance(o, ObjectId):
            return str(o)
        else:
            return super().default(o)


class ObjectIdConverter(BaseConverter):
    def to_python(self, value):
        return ObjectId(value)

    def to_url(self, value):
        return str(value)
```

*app.py*

```
from .mongoflask import MongoJSONEncoder, ObjectIdConverter

def create_app():
    app = Flask(__name__)
    app.json_encoder = MongoJSONEncoder
    app.url_map.converters['objectid'] = ObjectIdConverter

    # Client sends their string, we interpret it as an ObjectId
    @app.route('/users/<objectid:user_id>')
    def show_user(user_id):
        # setup not shown, pretend this gets us a pymongo db object
        db = get_db()

        # user_id is a bson.ObjectId ready to use with pymongo!
        result = db.users.find_one({'_id': user_id})

        # And jsonify returns normal looking json!
        # {"_id": "5b6b6959828619572d48a9da",
        #  "name": "Will",
        #  "birthday": "1990-03-17T00:00:00Z"}
        return jsonify(result)


    return app
```

Why do this instead of serving BSON or [mongod extended JSON](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/mongodb-extended-json)?

I think serving mongo special JSON puts a burden on client applications. Most client apps will not care using mongo objects in any complex way. If I serve extended json, now I have to use it server side, and the client side. `ObjectId` and `Timestamp` are easier to work with as strings and this keeps all this mongo marshalling madness quarantined to the server.

```
{
  "_id": "5b6b6959828619572d48a9da",
  "created_at": "2018-08-08T22:06:17Z"
}
```

I think this is less onerous to work with for *most* applications than.

```
{
  "_id": {"$oid": "5b6b6959828619572d48a9da"},
  "created_at": {"$date": 1533837843000}
}
```

Answer (score 11):

For those who need to return the data thru Jsonify with Flask:

```
cursor = db.collection.find()
data = []
for doc in cursor:
    doc['_id'] = str(doc['_id']) # This does the trick!
    data.append(doc)
return jsonify(data)
```

Answer (score 9):

You could try:

objectid = str(ObjectId("51948e86c25f4b1d1c0d303c"))

Answer (score 6):

in my case I needed something like this:

```
class JsonEncoder():
    def encode(self, o):
        if '_id' in o:
            o['_id'] = str(o['_id'])
        return o
```

Comment: +1 Ha ! Could it have been more simpler  Generally speaking; to avoid all the fuzz with custom encoders and bson importing, _cast ObjectID to string_:
`object['_id'] = str(object['_id'])`

Answer (score 4):

This is how I've recently fixed the error

```
    @app.route('/')
    def home():
        docs = []
        for doc in db.person.find():
            doc.pop('_id') 
            docs.append(doc)
        return jsonify(docs)
```

Comment: in this case you are not passing  '_id' attribute , instead just deleted '_id' and passed other attributes of doc

Answer (score 4):

I know I'm posting late but thought it would help at least a few folks!

Both the examples mentioned by tim and defuz(which are top voted) works perfectly fine. However, there is a minute difference which could be significant at times.

1. The following method adds one extra field which is redundant and may not be ideal in all the cases

Pymongo provides json_util - you can use that one instead to handle BSON types

Output: {
  "_id": {
    "$oid": "abc123"
  }
}

2. Where as the JsonEncoder class gives the same output in the string format as we need and we need to use json.loads(output) in addition. But it leads to

Output: {
  "_id": "abc123"
  }

Even though, the first method looks simple, both the method need very minimal effort.

Comment: this is very useful for the `pytest-mongodb` plugin when creating fixtures

Answer (score 4):

I would like to provide an additional solution that improves the accepted answer. I have previously provided the answers in another thread [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/56908399/3751268).

```
from flask import Flask
from flask.json import JSONEncoder

from bson import json_util

from . import resources

# define a custom encoder point to the json_util provided by pymongo (or its dependency bson)
class CustomJSONEncoder(JSONEncoder):
    def default(self, obj): return json_util.default(obj)

application = Flask(__name__)
application.json_encoder = CustomJSONEncoder

if __name__ == "__main__":
    application.run()
```

Answer (score 4):

If you want to send it as a JSON response you need to format in two steps

1. Using `json_util.dumps()` from bson to covert `ObjectId` in BSON response to
   JSON compatible format i.e. `"_id": {"$oid": "123456789"}`

The above JSON Response obtained from `json_util.dumps()`  will have backslashes and quotes

2. To remove backslashes and quotes use `json.loads()` from `json`

```py
from bson import json_util
import json

bson_data = [{'_id': ObjectId('123456789'), 'field': 'somedata'},{'_id': ObjectId('123456781'), 'field': 'someMoredata'}]

json_data_with_backslashes = json_util.dumps(bson_data)

# output will look like this
# "[{\"_id\": {\"$oid\": \"123456789\"}, \"field\": \"somedata\"},{\"_id\": {\"$oid\": \"123456781\"}, \"field\": \"someMoredata\"}]"

json_data = json.loads(json_data_with_backslashes)

# output will look like this
# [{"_id": {"$oid": "123456789"},"field": "somedata"},{"_id": {"$oid": "123456781"},"field": "someMoredata"}]
```

Answer (score 3):

If you will not be needing the _id of the records I will recommend unsetting it when querying the DB which will enable you to print the returned records directly e.g

To unset the _id when querying and then print data in a loop you write something like this

```
records = mycollection.find(query, {'_id': 0}) #second argument {'_id':0} unsets the id from the query
for record in records:
    print(record)
```

Answer (score 2):

Flask's jsonify provides security enhancement as described in [JSON Security](http://flask.pocoo.org/docs/0.10/security/#json-security). If custom encoder is used with Flask, its better to consider the 
points discussed in the [JSON Security](http://flask.pocoo.org/docs/0.10/security/#json-security)

Answer (score 2):

If you don't want `_id` in response, you can refactor your code something like this:

```
jsonResponse = getResponse(mock_data)
del jsonResponse['_id'] # removes '_id' from the final response
return jsonResponse
```

This will remove the `TypeError: ObjectId('') is not JSON serializable` error.

Answer (score 1):

```py
from bson.objectid import ObjectId
from core.services.db_connection import DbConnectionService

class DbExecutionService:
     def __init__(self):
        self.db = DbConnectionService()

     def list(self, collection, search):
        session = self.db.create_connection(collection)
        return list(map(lambda row: {i: str(row[i]) if isinstance(row[i], ObjectId) else row[i] for i in row}, session.find(search))
```

Answer (score 1):

```
    @app.route('/users', methods = ['GET'])
       def get_users():
       online_users = mongo.db.users.find({})
       list_users = list(online_users)
       json_users = json.dumps(list_users, default=json_util.default)
       return Response(json_users, mimetype='application/json')
```

This is how I made it working

Answer (score 0):

**SOLUTION for: mongoengine + marshmallow**

If you use `mongoengine` and `marshamallow` then this solution might be applicable for you.

Basically, I imported `String` field from marshmallow, and I overwritten default `Schema id` to be `String` encoded.

```py
from marshmallow import Schema
from marshmallow.fields import String

class FrontendUserSchema(Schema):

    id = String()

    class Meta:
        fields = ("id", "email")
```