# Flask-PyMongo - Object of type InsertOneResult is not JSON serializable

Tags: python, flask, pymongo, flask-pymongo

i have an api and i am trying to store/post a user object using Flask-Pymongo.

but, i get the following error

> File
>   "/home/kay/.local/share/virtualenvs/server-iT4jZt3h/lib/python3.7/site-packages/flask/json/**i│
>   nit**.py", line 321, in jsonify
>   │
>       dumps(data, indent=indent, separators=separators) + '\n',                                        │   File
>   "/home/kay/.local/share/virtualenvs/server-iT4jZt3h/lib/python3.7/site-packages/flask/json/**i│
>   nit**.py", line 179, in dumps
>   │
>       rv = _json.dumps(obj, **kwargs)                                                                  │   File "/usr/lib/python3.7/json/**init**.py", line 238, in dumps
>   │
>       **kw).encode(obj)                                                                                │   File "/usr/lib/python3.7/json/encoder.py", line 201, in encode
>   │
>       chunks = list(chunks)                                                                            │   File "/usr/lib/python3.7/json/encoder.py", line 438, in
>   _iterencode                                │
>       o = _default(o)                                                                                  │   File "/home/kay/link/server/src/run.py", line 18, in default
>   │
>       return json.JSONEncoder.default(self, o)                                                         │   File "/usr/lib/python3.7/json/encoder.py", line 179, in default
>   │
>       raise TypeError(f'Object of type {o.**class**.**name**} '                                        │ TypeError: Object of type InsertOneResult is not JSON serializable

**app/users/resource.py**

```
from flask_restful import Resource
from flask import jsonify, request
from .repository import UsersRepository
from db import mongo


class UsersResource(Resource):

    def __init__(self):

        self.repository = UsersRepository()

    def get(self):

        data = {"Users": "Resource"}
        res = data, 200
        return res

    def post(self):

        req = request.get_json()

        user = {
            "email": req.get("email"),
            "password": req.get("password")
        }

        result = mongo.db.users.insert_one(user)

        return jsonify(result)
```

**run.py**

```
from flask import Flask
from app import api_bp
from db import mongo
from bson.objectid import ObjectId
import json
import datetime
import os

class JSONEncoder(json.JSONEncoder):

    def default(self, o):
        if isinstance(o, ObjectId):
            return str(o)
        if isinstance(o, set):
            return list(o)
        if isinstance(o, datetime.datetime):
            return str(o)
        return json.JSONEncoder.default(self, o)



def create_app(config_filename):

    app = Flask(__name__)
    app.config.from_object(config_filename)
    app.register_blueprint(api_bp, url_prefix='/api')

    mongo.init_app(app)

    app.json_encoder = JSONEncoder

    return app


# def logger():


# def database():


if __name__ == "__main__":
    app = create_app("config")
    app.run(host='0.0.0.0', port=8080, debug=True)
```

Comment: Please paste the traceback here!

Comment: I updated the question @Feng

Comment: The `insert_one` method returns an instance of [`InsertOneResult`](http://api.mongodb.com/python/current/api/pymongo/results.html#pymongo.results.InsertOneResult) which is not JSON serializable as indicated on the traceback. You may want to return the [`inserted_id`](http://api.mongodb.com/python/current/api/pymongo/results.html#pymongo.results.InsertOneResult.inserted_id) instead.

Answer (score 4):

I believe that following previous suggestion you can find the answers. But I would like to provide another solution that simplifies it.

The solution assumes that `pymongo` and `flask` packages are installed:

```
from flask import Flask
from flask.json import JSONEncoder

from bson import json_util

from . import resources

# define a custom encoder point to the json_util provided by pymongo (or its dependency bson)
class CustomJSONEncoder(JSONEncoder):
    def default(self, obj): return json_util.default(obj)

application = Flask(__name__)
application.json_encoder = CustomJSONEncoder

if __name__ == "__main__":
    application.run()
```

Answer (score 1):

1. from bson.objectid import ObjectId
2. from bson import json_util

   - use pymongo **json_util bson** to handle BSON types
3. use force=true when getting json input :

   - req = request.get_json(force=true)
4. use default values when getting dict fields like :

   - req.get("email", "")

you can check if fields are empty or not before inserting into mongo.

Answer (score 1):

Simple Solution I found from here is

[TypeError: ObjectId('') is not JSON serializable](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16586180/typeerror-objectid-is-not-json-serializable)

Response -> bson dumps (searlization) -> json loads (deserialization)

Code is as follows :

```
from bson.json_util import dumps,RELAXED_JSON_OPTIONS
import json


def post(self,name):
        dream = {'name':name , 'price' : 12.00 }
        dreams.append(dream)
        dreamDao.addDream(dream) #MongoDB Call to Insert Data 
        bs = dumps(dream,json_options=RELAXED_JSON_OPTIONS) #Now dream has Response Which will have ObjectId
        return json.loads(bs) , 201
```

Answer (score 1):

The line `TypeError: Object of type InsertOneResult is not JSON serializable` describes the problem. `insert_one()` returns an [`InsertOneResult` object](http://api.mongodb.com/python/current/api/pymongo/results.html#pymongo.results.InsertOneResult), which contains the inserted ID (as @styvane's comment suggested) as well as a flag indicating whether the write was ack'd by the database. Other operations have similar result objects, and none of them are JSON serializable.

A future version of Flask-PyMongo may add helpers to support this, you can follow https://github.com/dcrosta/flask-pymongo/issues/62 to add ideas and suggestions.

Answer (score 0):

It seems that what you post to server is not a valid json object. So you should debug what you got.

```
class UsersResource(Resource):

    def post(self):
        # debug
        print("request.args is {}".format(request.args))
        print("request.form is {}".format(request.form))
        print("request.data is {}".format(request.data))

        req = request.get_json()

        user = {
            "email": req.get("email"),
            "password": req.get("password")
        }

        result = mongo.db.users.insert_one(user)

        return jsonify(result)
```

Answer (score 0):

```
from flask_pymongo import Pymongo
import json
import pandas as pd

user = pd.DataFrame(user)

mongo.db.users.insert_one({'email':json.loads(user[0].to_json(orient='index')),                            
                       'password':json.loads(user[1].to_json(orient='index'))})
```

This will throw up errors if your objects are already json. If they aren't though, it'll turn them into json and load them all in one go.