# Creating a proper JSON string using python

Tags: python, json, mongodb

Hi I am new to python programming. Here I use dumps to get the output from my mongodb. But I get a malformed JSON string error in PostMan.

My Code is:

```
cursor = db.Details.find()
    for document in (yield cursor.to_list(length=100)):
        self.write(bson.json_util.dumps(document))
```

My output is:

```
{"Name": "Will","_id": {"$oid": "55a8f075a382c32392b75bad"}}
{"Name": "Alex", "_id": {"$oid": "55acc2205d8882ef8a667d34"}}
{"data": null, "status": "success"}
```

How I want my output to be:

```
{"data": [
   {"Name": "Will","_id": {"$oid": "55a8f075a382c32392b75bad"}},
   {"Name": "Alex", "_id": {"$oid": "55acc2205d8882ef8a667d34"}}
], "status": "success"}
```

Please help me.

Thanks in advance

My Output screenshot from PostMan
[image]

Comment: see also http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31514500/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

How about you first save everything in a list and then dump that list to `json`?

```
data = []
cursor = db.Details.find()
    for document in (yield cursor.to_list(length=100)):
        data.append(document)

self.write(bson.json_util.dumps({"data": data}))
```

**Edit**:
For getting the `success` variable like your desired output, you could try

```
data = []
status = ""

cursor = db.Details.find()
    for document in (yield cursor.to_list(length=100)):
        if 'status' in document: # check if key 'status' in document
            status = document[status]
        else:
            data.append(document)

self.write(bson.json_util.dumps({"data": data, "status": status}))
```

Comment: Good luck. But you get my vote. Various people have tried to tell the OP the same thing now for days. Add a "success" key and value in the final dict and it should mirror exactly what is asked for.

Comment: Ok...? I just noticed the `success` key was missing in my output :) @[tony-roczz](http://stackoverflow.com/users/5039470/tony-roczz) Does this work for you?

Comment: @adrianus Thanks for the help it works. My output is as desired. But I am getting this `{"status": "success", "data": null}` additionally. Anyway to solve that

Comment: @TonyRoczz I'm sorry, I mistyped (key `success` instead of `status`), could you try again?

Comment: @adrianus It works thank you after my output I am getting the `{"status": "success", "data": null}`. Is there way to avoid this.