# Mongoengine Django Rest Framework - Serializer Error - ReferenceField is not JSON serializable

Tags: django-rest-framework, mongoengine

Everything works great until the `ObjectID` value of the ReferenceField no longer points to a valid document. Then The `ObjectID` is left as the value, and json doesn't know how to serialize this.

How do I deal with invalid ReferenceFields?

E.g.

```
class Food(Document):
    name = StringField()
    owner = ReferenceField("Person")

class Person(Document):
    first_name = StringField()
    last_name = StringField()
    ...


p = Person(...)
apple = Food(name="apple", owner=p)
p.delete() # might be the wrong method, but you get the idea
```

At this point, attempting to fetch a list of foods via the REST API will fail with the `is not JSON serializable` error, since `apple.owner` no longer points to an owner that exists.

Comment: Are you also using `django-rest-framework-mongoengine`?

Answer (score 1):

Since you are using DRF with mongoengine, you must be using [`django-rest-framework-mongoengine`](https://github.com/umutbozkurt/django-rest-framework-mongoengine).

Apparenly, its a bug in django-rest-framework-mongoengine. Check this open issue on Github which was reported recently regarding the same.

https://github.com/umutbozkurt/django-rest-framework-mongoengine/issues/91

One way is to write your own `JSONEncoder` for this. This [link](https://stackoverflow.com/a/16586277/4921103) might help.

Another option is to use the [`json_util`](http://api.mongodb.org/python/current/api/bson/json_util.html#module-bson.json_util) library of [`Pymongo`](http://api.mongodb.org/python/current/index.html#pymongo-release-documentation). They provide explicit BSON conversion to and from json.

As per `json-util` docs:

> This module provides two helper methods `dumps` and `loads` that wrap the
>   native json methods and provide explicit BSON conversion to and from
>   json. This allows for specialized encoding and decoding of BSON
>   documents into Mongo Extended JSON‘s Strict mode. This lets you encode
>   / decode BSON documents to JSON even when they use special BSON types.

Comment: Creating your own `JSONEncoder` might help. Check this ans. http://stackoverflow.com/a/16586277/4921103

Comment: Hrmm, I'll look at that. Thanks!

Comment: Also, another option is the [`json_util`](http://api.mongodb.org/python/current/api/bson/json_util.html#module-bson.json_util) library in [`Pymongo`](http://api.mongodb.org/python/current/index.html#pymongo-release-documentation). They provide explicit `BSON` conversion to and from `json`.

Comment: yeah, json_util is what I generally use for that. It's more I'm not sure where to tie that in/what to override in django-rest-framework-mongoengine to make it work.

Comment: I think you can do that by creating your `CustomJSONRenderer` and then defining it as default renderer in your views or in the project's settings.