# How return list on Python and Flask?

Tags: python, list, api, flask

I'm trying to return this list in flask. Teacher is a class and returns objects.

```
@app.route('/v1/teachers', methods=['GET'])
def getTeachers():
  teachers = []
  for teacher in Teacher.objects:
    teachers.append(teacher)
  return teachers
```

This code returns the typical error of 
`TypeError: 'list' object is not callable The view function did not return a valid response.`

I'm going crazy and I don't know what's going on. Does anyone know?

Thank you!!

**EDIT:**

I've already worked it out. The problem was not how to return the list, the problem was the serialization in JSON of the objects.

```
@app.route('/v1/teachers', methods=['GET'])
def getTeachers():
  teachers = []
  for teacher in Teacher.objects:
     teacherJson = teacher.to_json()
     teacherData = json.loads(teacherJson)
     teachers.append(teacherData)
  return jsonify({'teachers': teachers})
```

Thanks for your help.

Comment: Have you tried checking the value in `Teacher.objects` ? Also, you might need to return response in json. So, you will need to pass this list in json format.

Comment: try `return json.dumps(teachers)`

Comment: This doesn't work, it gives me back this error:
`TypeError: <Teacher: Teacher object> is not JSON serializable`

Answer (score 27):

You can't return a list directly from flask view.please try to jsonify

```
from flask import jsonify
@app.route('/v1/teachers', methods=['GET'])
def getTeachers():
   teachers = []
   for teacher in Teacher.objects:
      teachers.append(teacher)
   return jsonify(teachers)
```

Comment: Does not work TypeError: Object of type List is not JSON serializable

Comment: This works at least for python 2.

Comment: @ajbraus take a look here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16586180/typeerror-objectid-is-not-json-serializable

Answer (score 4):

You are returning a list, Flask expects a response to be returned.

```
from flask import jsonify

@app.route('/v1/teachers', methods=['GET'])
def getTeachers():
  teachers = []
  for teacher in Teacher.objects:
    teachers.append(teacher)
  return jsonify({"teachers": teachers})
```

Comment: This doesn't work, it gives me back this error: 
`TypeError: <Teacher: Teacher object> is not JSON serializable`

Comment: This does not work.

Comment: You can see the edit from OP in his answer. The `teacher` object has to be converted to JSON here if it's not automatically convertible.

Comment: `def test():
      test = ['1','2','3']
      return jsonify({'test':test})`