# mongoDB Object of type 'ObjectId' is not JSON serializable

Tags: python, mongodb, pymongo

I am trying to read file from mongoDB to local.

My code are as below:
STRING = "myLocalPath"
PATH = STRING + ".json"

```
 with open(PATH,"w") as f:
     d = users.find({'Credit' : str("The Associated Press") },
                {'article_id':1,'Byline':1} ) 


    for i in d:
        f.write(json.dumps(i)+'\n')
        f.close()
```

I am getting Error - Object of type 'ObjectId' is not JSON serializable..
please suggest.

Comment: `json` doesn't know how to serialize pymongo object id class `ObjectId`. You can use `json_util` or create your own encoder as suggested in https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16586180/typeerror-objectid-is-not-json-serializable

Comment: Possible duplicate of [TypeError: ObjectId('') is not JSON serializable](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16586180/typeerror-objectid-is-not-json-serializable)

Comment: Do you need the `_id` field in your local copy? If not you could sth. like this.
`d = users.find({'Credit' : str("The Associated Press") }, {'article_id': 1,'Byline': 1, '_id': 0} )`

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

```
from bson import json_util
 for i in d:
        f.write(json.dumps(i, default = json_util.default)+'\n')
        f.close()
```

OR

```
import json
 for i in d:
        f.write(json.dumps(i, default = str)+'\n')
        f.close()
```