# Django + MongoDB + Djongo: can't json serialize ObjectId

Tags: django, mongodb, djongo

I'm creating a Django APP with MongoDB using Djongo.

When I try `json.dumps(my_queryset, cls=DjangoJSONEncoder)` I get the following error.

> Object of type ObjectId is not JSON serializable

**The model**

```
class Productos(models.Model):
    _id = models.ObjectIdField()
    id_anwen = models.IntegerField(help_text="Pedido Mínimo", blank=True, null=True, default=1)
    codigo_kinemed = models.CharField(max_length=100, blank=True, null=True)
    codigo_barra = models.CharField(max_length=100, blank=True, null=True)
    codigo_inner = models.CharField(max_length=100, blank=True, null=True)
    codigo_master = models.CharField(max_length=100, blank=True, null=True)
    item_number = models.CharField(max_length=100, blank=True, null=True)
    objects = models.DjongoManager()
```

**Some test**

If I remove `_id = models.ObjectIdField()` json dumps works fine but I don't get the object's ID info in the JSON.

How can I serialize MongoDB's _id field for a JSON?

Any clues welcome. Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

The solution in this post works fine: [TypeError: ObjectId('') is not JSON serializable](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16586180/typeerror-objectid-is-not-json-serializable)

I just copy it here because teh question is more targeted and it might be easier to find.