# how to resolve a TypeError: Object of type ObjectId is not JSON serializable using flask-jwt

Tags: python, json, flask-restful, werkzeug, flask-jwt

I have an error that I cannot resolve. here is the error I get when I authenticate with postman: **TypeError: Object of type ObjectId is not JSON serializable // Werkzeug Debugger**
**File "C:\Users\Amoungui\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\Lib\json\encoder.py", line 179, in default
raise TypeError(f'Object of type {o.**class**.**name**} '
TypeError: Object of type ObjectId is not JSON serializable**

Here is my code, I followed the official documentation, but at this does not work I do not understand. here is the link of the documentation: https://pythonhosted.org/Flask-JWT/

customer.py

```
from flask import jsonify, make_response
from config.mongoose import db
import bson 

class Customer(db.Document):
    _id = db.ObjectIdField(default=bson.ObjectId, primary_key=True) #bson.ObjectId
    tel = db.StringField()
    password = db.StringField()
    
    def to_json(self):
        return {
            "_id": self._id,
            "tel": self.tel,
            "password": self.password,
        }
     
    def findAll(self):
        users = []
        for user in self.objects:
            users.append(user)
            
        return users
```

service.py

```
from Models.Customer import Customer
from werkzeug.security import safe_str_cmp

find_by_username = {u.tel:u for u in Customer.objects}

find_by_id = {u._id: u for u in Customer.objects}

def auth(username, password):
    user = find_by_username.get(username, None)
    if user and safe_str_cmp(user.password.encode('utf-8'), password.encode('utf-8')):
        return user
    
def identity(payload):
    _id = payload['identity']
    return find_by_id.get(_id)
```

thank's for your help

Answer (score 0):

The error message suggests its an issue with serializing `bson.ObjectId`. Have you tried solutions suggested in: [type error objectid](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16586180/typeerror-objectid-is-not-json-serializable)

Comment: I change the customer class like this 
``` _id = db.ObjectIdField() #bson.ObjectId```
I have the new error: 
 **identity = getattr(identity, 'id') or identity['id']
  File "C:\Users\Amoungui\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\Lib\site-packages\mongoengine\base\document.py", line 250, in __getitem__        
    raise KeyError(name)
KeyError: 'id'**

Answer (score 0):

I change the customer class like this

```
from flask import jsonify, make_response
from config.mongoose import db
import bson 

class Customer(db.Document):
    _id = db.ObjectIdField() #bson.ObjectId
    tel = db.StringField()
    password = db.StringField()
    
    def to_json(self):
        return {
            "_id": self._id,
            "tel": self.tel,
            "password": self.password,
        }
     
    def findAll(self):
        users = []
        for user in self.objects:
            users.append(user)
            
        return users
```

I have the new error:
**identity = getattr(identity, 'id') or identity['id']
File "C:\Users\Amoungui\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\Lib\site-packages\mongoengine\base\document.py", line 250, in **getitem**

raise KeyError(name)
KeyError: 'id'**