# TypeError TypeError: Object of type ObjectId is not JSON serializable

Tags: python, flask, pymongo, flask-mongoengine

I am trying to write a Python Flask program to read my MongoDB Database and output the table in Json format. My flask seems to run, as I am able to get into the default endpoint, but my second endpoint gives me the below error. Any feedback would be appreciated.

```
TypeError: Object of type ObjectId is not JSON serializable
```

This is my Code.

My Database name is "movies_db" and the Collection name is "movie_info".

```py
from flask import Flask, jsonify
from pymongo import MongoClient

app = Flask(__name__)

# Replace with MongoDB connection details
mongo_client = MongoClient('mongodb://localhost:27017/')
db = mongo_client['movies_db']

@app.route('/')
def index():
    return 'Welcome to my Project!'


import json

@app.route('/export-json', methods=['GET', 'POST'])
def export_json():
    collection_name = 'movie_info'  

    data = list(db[collection_name].find({}))

    # Convert data to JSON using Flask's jsonify
    json_data = jsonify(data).get_json()

    # Write JSON data to a file
    with open('data.json', 'w') as json_file:
        json.dump(json_data, json_file, indent=4)

    return jsonify({'message': 'Data exported to data.json'})

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run()`
```

I've tried using the solution in this link, but still no luck.

[TypeError: ObjectId('') is not JSON serializable](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16586180/typeerror-objectid-is-not-json-serializable)

Comment: See the following answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/18405626/1260006 - `json_util` may help you with serialization of `ObjectId`

Comment: that's the first thing I tried, but no luck. Thanks for trying to help!

Comment: I haven't tried it, but what happens with `data = [bson.json_util.dumps(doc) for doc in db[collection_name].find({})]`?

Comment: The strange part is that my teammate tried it on his computer and it worked. I was however able to ask my professor about this, and this is the fix he recommended. It worked for me. 


'''data = list(db[collection_name].find({}, {'_id': 0})'''

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you're not bothered about the `_id` fields you can exclude it by changing your `find()` to exlcude the field.

```
data = list(db[collection_name].find({}, {'_id': 0})
```

This won't help if you have other `ObjectId`s in the record though.

Comment: Thank you very much! I was able to ask my professor the same question today, and this was the fix he recommended too. Doing that fixed the issue. And yes, I don't need the '_id' field.